# What is the default CellValueFactory for a TableColumn?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, factory, tablecolumn

I want to know what the deault TableColumn CellValueFactory is. I know it is possible to get the default CellFactory by using TableColumn.DEFAULT_CELL_FACTORY, is there a way to access the CellValueFactory in the same way?

I ask because I have a function that defines a custom CellValueFactory for a TableColumn, this allows me to fill the column with values when the user presses a button. But then this same column can later be cleared and values can be added by typing a value and pressing enter.

I believe adding values to the column via typing only works when the CellValueFactory is the default.

I have tried connecting it to my model but this is not how I want it to work.

My custom CellValueFactory is the following:

```
tableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<List<String>, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {

@Override
public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<List<String>, String> data) {
        return new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(data.getValue().get(0));
    }
});
```

This works as intended, however when I fill the TableColumn using this CellValueFactory, and then press the button that clears the table, adds a number of rows (allowing the user to type values), the rows are created and added to the table but are not displayed.

However, the rows are displayed correctly if the user presses the button to type values first (instead of auto-filling the rows first). I have defined a CellFactory when this button is pressed, but no CellValueFactory.

I hope that if I can reset the CellValueFactory when the button is pressed, the table will work as intended.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but I believe the default value factory is simply `null`, in which case the table can't extract the value from the model. And editing works _by default_ only if the value factory returns a `WritableValue` _and_ that `WritableValue` writes back to the model. This is handled through the default `TableColumn.onEditCommit` handler.

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work, for some silly reason I was expecting it to be something more convoluted.